# Dredge output R

Tags: r, feature-selection

I have a question concerning the output of a “[dredge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.43.15/topics/dredge)” function of the “MuMIn” package in R. I am trying to build a model with ecological variables that best explain my species occupancy data for 41 sites in the field (which I have gathered from camera traps). For this particular run I have preselected two variables that could explain my occupancy (“Palm” and “Grassland”) and I have put in some variables that could affect detection. The output of the first 10 models of the dredge are shown below:

[image]
Just to see if I understand my output correctly:
I cannot distinguish between the top 9 models (because the delta value is <2)?
Most of my top models will not include either “Grassland” or “Palm” as variables explaining my occupancy data, meaning that they are bad predictors?

What exactly do the adjR^2 and weight values mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the documentation of the output ‘model selection object’ https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MuMIn/versions/1.43.15/topics/model.selection.object. See more details in Johnson and Omland 2004 “model selection in ecology and evolution” https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169534703003458

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).

Comment: You'd do best to not do this.  *Dredge*, in the name of the function, is not a complement.  This is not a good way to determine which variables are relevant.  It may help you to read my answer here: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290).